# C# Compressed Size of a Bitmap without savig it

Tags: c#, file, bitmap, compression

I have a simple C# script that generates a `Bitmap`, saves it to the hard drive (PNG), checks the file Size and based on the size of the file it will move or delete the image.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
bmp.save(@"C:\User\...\image.png");

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo (@"C:\User\...\image.png");

if (fi.length > 50000){
//do Something
}
```

Is there any other way to get the compressed (RLE) size of the `Bitmap` without storing it locally?

Comment: What makes you think png uses RLE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save the image to a [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    if (ms.Length > 50000){
        //do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `.Length` reliable? I'd think `.Position` should be the actual end of the written data.